# How to get access to pallet storage from tests

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, storage, frame, testing

I have approvals map in my pallet
[image]

[image]
So when i try to get value from my storage, I'm getting this error

[image]

So how to properly use pallet storage in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a getter for your storage.

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn approvals)]
pub type Approvals<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<...>;
```

Then it could be used in your test.

```rust
assert_eq!(TemplateModule::approvals(whitelisted_caller(), recipient), Some(true));
```